# Inserting multiple rows with PostGIS points with Psycopg3

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, psycopg3

I'm using psycopg3 to insert multiple rows into a table using the following function:

```
async def execute_values(self, command_with_placeholders, values) -> None:
    placeholders = sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(values[0]))
    command = sql.SQL(command_with_placeholders).format(placeholders=placeholders)
    async with (await self.conn).cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.executemany(command, values)
```

Calling it with the following parameters fails when I include a non empty `location`:

```
insert_sessions_command = """
        INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, start_time, last_activity_time, end_time, ip,
            user_agent, country_code, region_code, location)
        VALUES ({placeholders});
    """
    await sql_db.execute_values(insert_sessions_command, [
        ('s1', datetime(2023, 1, 1), datetime(2023, 1, 2), None, '1.2.3.4', None,
         'NZ', 'NZ-CAN', 'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(172.6306, 43.5320), 4326)'),
    ]
```

Doing the following using a Postgres console works:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, start_time, last_activity_time, end_time, ip,
                user_agent, country_code, region_code, location)
            VALUES ('s1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', null, '1.2.3.4', null,
             'NZ', 'NZ-CAN', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(172.6306, 43.5320), 4326));
```

So I guess the psycopg code fails because it encloses the point with quotations, like the following wrong Postgres command:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (session_id, start_time, last_activity_time, end_time, ip,
                user_agent, country_code, region_code, location)
            VALUES ('s1', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', null, '1.2.3.4', null,
             'NZ', 'NZ-CAN', 'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(172.6306, 43.5320), 4326)');
```

In both cases the error is

```
parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "ST" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $9 = '...'
```

How do I make the Psycopg code not enclose the point string with quotations to fix it?

Comment: 1) `execute_values()` is not found in `psycopg3`, so are instead using `psycopg2`. 2) This: `'ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(172.6306, 43.5320), 4326)'` is a string and that will not resolve to function calls. I'm guessing you will need to build with `sql.Identifier()`.

Comment: execute_values() is the function I defined in the first code segment. I mentioned that the problem is `'ST_SetSRID(...)'` resolves to a string, but I'm not sure how to use `sql.Identifier()` when I need to build the command programmatically accepting dynamic values with `sql.Placeholder()`s.

Comment: 1) Oops missed the function definition. 2) A quick and dirty example: `fnc_str = sql.SQL('select {ran_func}()') cur.execute(fnc_str.format(ran_func=sql.Identifier('random')) cur.fetchone() (0.37156436300946294,)`

Comment: I tried using `sql.SQL('ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({0}, {1}), 4326)').format(
    sql.Identifier('172.6306'),
    sql.Identifier('43.5320')
)`
Instead of the string I had in the values tuple, but I got `cannot adapt type 'Composed' using placeholder '%s' (format: AUTO)`.  It might have worked if I didn't use the sql.Placeholders...

Comment: You did this backwards `ST_SetSRID` and `ST_MakePoint` are the identifiers, `'172.6306'` and `'43.5320'` are values. That is why you are getting the errors.

Answer (score 0):

As simple example to show what I am getting at:

```
import psycopg
from psycopg import sql

con = psycopg.connect('dbname=test host=localhost user=postgres')
cur = con.cursor()

sql_str = sql.SQL('select {round}({random}()::numeric, %s)')
cur.execute(sql_str.format(round=sql.Identifier('round'), random=sql.Identifier('random')), [3]).fetchone()
(Decimal('0.357'),)

cur.execute(sql_str.format(round=sql.Identifier('round'), random=sql.Identifier('random')), [2]).fetchone()
(Decimal('0.50'),)
```